# Erro ao utilizar ISDATE em CASE WHEN

Tags: sql, sql-server

Olá, pessoal. Estou rodando a query abaixo e está apresentando o erro: "Operand type clash: int is incompatible with date".

Minha intenção ao realizar esta query é validar se o campo VENCIMENTO_ORIGINAL é uma data válida, e caso seja, validar se o dia desta data é igual ao dia do campo DTINICIO. Alguém sabe o que poderia estar dando errado? Segue a query abaixo:

```
  UPDATE A
SET DIVERGENCIA_DE_VENCIMENTO = 'NÃO'
FROM  TMP_LAYOUT_DIRETRIZES A
WHERE ISDATE(A.VENCIMENTO_ORIGINAL) = 1
AND CASE WHEN ISDATE(A.VENCIMENTO_ORIGINAL) = 0 THEN CAST(NULL AS DATE)
    ELSE DAY(CONVERT(DATE,VENCIMENTO_ORIGINAL,103))
    END = DAY(CONVERT(DATE,DTINICIO,103))
```

EDIT: Segue exemplo dos dados da tabela TMP_LAYOUT_DIRETRIZES:

```
vencimento_original dtinicio
2018-09-20          20/09/2014
2018-09-20          20/09/2015
2018-09-20          20/12/2015
2018-09-20          20/06/2016
2018-09-20          20/08/2016
2018-09-20          20/03/2017
2018-09-20          20/09/2017
2018-09-28          20/04/2018
2018-09-20          20/07/2018
2018-09-20          20/07/2018
```

Comment: `CAST(NULL AS DATE)`? Isso não faz sentido nenhum. Coloca direto `NULL` nesse caso, sem o `CAST`

Comment: Quando eu faço isso, aí aparece outro erro: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: Paulo, neste caso, nem o CAST  e nem o CONVERT vão funcionar. NULL é diferente de 'NULL', e neste caso, qualquer conversão p/ date no sql server você vai precisar ter uma data que seja possível converter.

Comment: Coloca um exemplo dos dados que tem nessa tabela `TMP_LAYOUT_DIRETRIZES` pra vermos dcomo está seu campo `VENCIMENTO_ORIGINAL` e `DTINICIO`

Comment: Suas datas não seguem um padrão. Tem umas que estão `YYYY-MM-DD` e outras estão `DD/MM/YYYY`

Comment: Eu coloquei SET DATEFORMAT DMY no início da query, e mesmo assim não consegui converter. Ambos os campos são varchar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O seu formato de datas não está igual para os dois campos:

```
UPDATE A
   SET DIVERGENCIA_DE_VENCIMENTO = 'NÃO'
  FROM  TMP_LAYOUT_DIRETRIZES A
 WHERE ISDATE(A.VENCIMENTO_ORIGINAL) = 1
   AND CASE
         WHEN ISDATE(A.VENCIMENTO_ORIGINAL) = 0 THEN NULL
         ELSE DAY(CONVERT(DATE, VENCIMENTO_ORIGINAL, 120))
       END = DAY(CONVERT(DATE, DTINICIO, 103))
```